# Why does onreadystatechange go before req.open on POST Ajax request

Tags: ajax, post, get

I understand from [this site](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml) that in the case of a `POST` Ajax request, we need to place the `request.onreadystatechange` function call before the `request.open` command.  In `GET` requests we typically place them in the opposite order.  Why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "typically" mean?  Where do you see documented that you are *supposed* to do that with `GET` requests?  `request.onreadystatechange` should always come first. By defining it after the request is initiated you open yourself up to the possibility that the event is fired prior to your handler being established.

Comment: That's just the way I've seen it and been taught to do it.

Comment: Well, now you know...and knowing is half the battle.